# How to generate non-temporal instructions?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, clang, icc

Intel's compiler has a [pragma](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/pragmas/intel-specific-pragma-reference/vector-1.html) that can be used to generate non-temporal stores. For example, I can write

```cpp
void square(const double* x, double* y, int n) {
#pragma vector nontemporal
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    y[i] = x[i] * x[i];
  }
}
```

and ICC will generate instructions like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/ecnq1P) (compiler-explorer)

```
...
  vmovntpd %ymm1, (%rsi,%r9,8) #4.5
...
```

Do gcc and clang have anything similar? (other than intrinsics)

The non-temporal store makes the code much faster. Using this benchmark

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <memory>

#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

static void generate_random_numbers(double* x, int n) {
  std::mt19937 rng{0};
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist{-1, 1};
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    x[i] = dist(rng);
  }
}

static void square(const double* x, double* y, int n) {
#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
#pragma vector nontemporal
#endif
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    y[i] = x[i] * x[i];
  }
}

static void BM_Square(benchmark::State& state) {
  const int n = state.range(0);
  std::unique_ptr<double[]> xptr{new double[n]};
  generate_random_numbers(xptr.get(), n);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::unique_ptr<double[]> yptr{new double[n]};
    square(xptr.get(), yptr.get(), n);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(yptr);
  }
}

BENCHMARK(BM_Square)->Arg(1000000);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

the non-temporal code runs almost twice as fast on my machine. Here are the full results:

icc:

```
> icc -O3 -march=native -std=c++11 benchmark.cpp -lbenchmark -lbenchmark_main
> ./a.out
------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                  Time             CPU   Iterations
------------------------------------------------------------
BM_Square/1000000     430889 ns       430889 ns         1372
```

clang:

```
> clang++ -O3 -march=native -std=c++11 benchmark.cpp -lbenchmark -lbenchmark_main
> ./a.out
------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                  Time             CPU   Iterations
------------------------------------------------------------
BM_Square/1000000     781672 ns       781470 ns          820
```

gcc:

```
> g++-mp-10 -O3 -march=native -std=c++11 benchmark.cpp -lbenchmark -lbenchmark_main
> ./a.out
------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                  Time             CPU   Iterations
------------------------------------------------------------
BM_Square/1000000     681684 ns       681533 ns          782
```

Note: clang has [__builtin_nontemporal_store](https://gitlab.liu.se/henhe459/clang-skepu/commit/2db8497948ecd5fe0552cef154e55a72a8eb083c); but when I try it, it won't generate non-temporal instructions ([compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/K5K67b))

Comment: `__builtin_nontemporal_store` does work with SSE types (e.g. `__m256d`). So it's probably not implemented for auto-vectorized loops, though that could be a nice addition.

Comment: Good to know. But I think intel has the better approach with their pragma: it's much less practical to integrate something like __builtin_nontemporal_store into an expression template library.

Comment: Just to state the obvious, if you actually had code doing multiple passes of pure-vertical operations over the same large array, it would be a big win to cache-block so you all the passes over the first 16kiB or 128kiB (half of L1d or L2 cache sizes, respectively, on typical microarchitectures), so you get cache hits from the later passes.  Then move on to the next chunk that fits in cache.  That's even better than using NT stores and having DRAM load + store.

Comment: There are substantial differences in the generated code between clang & icc beyond the use of `vmovntpd`. Did you try to benchmark the icc generated code without the pragma? Interesting to know what are the results