# Advice on improving a function's performace

Tags: c++, optimization, graphics, drm

For a project I'm working on, I require a function which copies the contents of a rectangular image into another via its pixel buffers.
The function needs to account for edge collisions on the destination image as the two images are rarely going to be the same size.

I'm looking for tips on the most optimal way to do this, as the function I'm using can copy a 720x480 image into a 1920x955 image in just under 1.5ms. That's fine on its own, but hardly optimal.

```
#define coord(x, y) ((void *) (dest + 4 * ((y) * width + (x))))
#define scoord(x, y) ((void *) (src + 4 * ((y) * src_width + (x))))

void copy_buffer(uint8_t* dest, int width, int height, uint8_t* src, int src_width, int src_height, int x, int y) {
    if (x + src_width < 0 || x >= width || y + src_height < 0 || y >= height || src_width <= 0 || src_height <= 0)
        return;

    for (int line = std::max(0, y); line < std::min(height, y + src_height); line++)
        memcpy(coord(std::max(0, x), line), scoord(-1 * std::min(0, x), -1 * std::min(0, y)), (std::min(x + src_width, width) - std::max(0, x)) * 4);

}
```

#### Some things I've considered

1. Multithreading seems suboptimal for several reasons;

   - Race conditions from simultaneous access to the same memory region,
   - Overhead from spawning and managing separate threads
2. Using my system's GPU

   - Effectively multithreading
   - Huge overhead for moving and managing data between GPU and CPU
   - Not portable to my target platform
3. Algorithmic optimisations such as calculating multi-image bounding boxes and adding **** loads more code to only render the regions of the image that will be visible

   - While I was planning on doing this anyway, I thought I'd mention it here to ask for further information on how to best achieve this
4. Using a library/os function to do this for me

   - I'm new-ish to programming on the low level, and especially to performance-oriented programming, so there's always the chance I've missed something.
   - I'm presently not using a multimedia framework like SFML, because I'm trying to focus on executable and codebase size, but if that's the best idea, so be it.

---

Whew, bit of a mouthful. I apologise, but I would seriously appreciate any pointers.

Extra notes: I'm writing for/on Linux embedded devices over the DRI/M interface.

---

##### Edit

As per @Jérôme Richard's comment, some information about my system

Development machine: Dell inspiron 15 7570, 16GB RAM, i7 8core + Ubuntu 21.04
Target machine: Raspberry Pi 3B (1GB RAM, Broadcom something-or-other) 4 cores 1.4GHz + Ubuntu Server for Pi

Compiler: GCC/G++ 11.2.0

Comment: Could you elaborate on computing line length? I'm not fully sure what you mean with that one

Comment: Using `memcpy` is a good idea and should be very fast already (the min/max should not take a significant portion of time in practice on your example). Did you enabled optimizations (ie. `-O3` flag for Clang/GCC as well as `-march=native`, and `/O2` for MSVC)? What are the target architecture (eg. ARM) and processor? If possible, can you provide information about the memory?

Comment: @AlexF Compilers (mostly) do such optimizations. In fact, the last version of GCC, Clang and MSVC succeed to generate a `memcpy`-based loop with less than 10 instructions on both x86 and ARM-V8. Such instructions should take only few cycles on performance-oriented modern processors. Almost all the time should be spent in the `memcpy` call (not inlined) which should be highly-optimized and memory bound but this point is very dependent of the target platform. Note that most instructions are used to push parameters to the `memcpy` call (few mov/lea) and the loop itself (few adds and a jump).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for your input, I've updated the question with some information about my system/target arch. I hadn't added optimisations, but enabling them seemed to give very similar, if not identical performance.

Comment: @AlexF My confusion lays in having to account for things like clipping. I can't just use the image stride etc. I have to use the "algorithm" above

Comment: Thank you for the information. Is the 1.5ms for the Dell or for the Raspberry? 1.5ms for the Dell machine seems very bad. However, they would be quite good for the raspberry 3B. (besides this, please note that you should have a i7-8550U processor with 4 core and not 8 based on what I can read).

Comment: My system reports 8 cores https://imgur.com/a/NcbGX5P

Comment: @JérômeRichard Just to let you know, I refactored the function to precalculate all the `min`/`max` values outside of the loop. Made no difference

Comment: Good to know. This make sense regarding the answer ;) . Assuming your processor is a i7-8550U, Intel report it has 4 core and 8 threads. See [here](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/122589/intel-core-i78550u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html). Your system report threads and not cores. 8 cores Intel processors have pretty high energy consumption that is not well suited for notebook yet.

Comment: It was until today that I praised myself for having 8 cores. Turns out you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mostly **bounded by memory operations** and more specifically the `memcpy` since compilers (like GCC 11) already optimize it aggressively. `memcpy` is generally very efficiently implemented. That being said, it is sometime sub-optimal. I think this is the case here. To understand why, we need to delve into the low-level architecture of mainstream modern processor and more specifically the *cache hierarchy*.

There are two main [writing cache policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) widely used in mainstream processors: the *write-back* policy (with write-allocate) and the *write-through* policy (without write-allocate). Intel processors and the BCM2837 (Cortex-A53) of the Raspberry Pi 3B use a *write-back policy with write-allocate*. Write allocation cause data at the missed-write location to be loaded to cache, followed by a write-hit operation. The thing is that **cache lines written to the last-level cache (LLC) need first to be read from RAM before being written back**. This can cause up to half the bandwidth to be wasted!

To address this issue when big arrays are written into the RAM (not fit in the LLC), **non-temporal instructions** have been designed. The goal of such instructions is to write directly into the RAM and bypass the cache hierarchy so not to cause cache pollution and better use the memory bandwidth.

`memcpy` is generally designed to use non-temporal instructions when a large buffer is copied. However, when many small buffers are copied, **`memcpy` cannot know that the overall set of buffer would be too big to fit in the LLC** or even that written data are not meant to be reused soon. In fact, sometime, even developers cannot know since the size of the computed buffer can be dependent of the user and the size of the LLC is dependent of the user target machine.

The bad news is that such instructions can hardly be used from a high-level code. ICC supports that using pragma directives, Clang has an experimental support with builtins and AFAIK GCC does not support that yet. OpenMP 5 provide a portable pragma directive for that but it is not yet implemented. For more information, please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63512013/how-to-generate-non-temporal-instructions).

On x86-64 processors, you can use the SSE and AVX intrinsics `_mm_stream_si128` and `_mm256_stream_si256`. Note that the pointers need to be aligned in memory.

On ARMv8 processors, there is an instruction `STNP` but it is only an hint and it is not really meant to bypass the cache. Moreover, the [Cortex-A53 specification](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/6040c321ee937942ba301626?token=) seems to only support non-temporal loads (not non-temporal stores). Put it shortly, [ARMv8 does not have such instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66686147/is-there-non-cacheable-cache-bypass-load-or-store-instruction-for-aarch64).

The good news is that the very recent ARMv9 instruction set adds new instructions for that. In fact it adds specific instructions for non-temporal copies. You can get the specification [here](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/61c04cbab691546d37bd2b87).

Since the Raspberry Pi 3B practical memory benchmarks indicates a read bandwidth of 2.7 GB/s and a write bandwidth of 2.4 GB/s. A copy of a 720x480 3-chanel image with write allocations would take about `720 * 480 * 3 * (1/2.4e9 + 2/2.7e9) = 1.2 ms` which is close to your reported execution time. It is also important to mention that read-write DRAM accesses tends to be a bit slower than plain reads or plain writes. If the `STNP` hint works well, it would results in 0.8 ms (optimal on this hardware). **If you want a faster execution time, then you need to work on smaller images**.

On you Dell machine with an Intel Kaby-Lake processor and certainly 1~2 2400MHz DDR4 memory channels, the practical throughput should be 12~35 GiB/s resulting in 0.1~0.3 ms to copy the image with the basic `memcpy` and 0.1~0.2 ms with the non-temporal instructions. Moreover, the LLC cache is much bigger so that the operations should be even faster with the basic `memcpy` as long as the image fit in the LLC (certainly less than 0.1 ms).

Comment: It's interesting that you mention it completing on the Dell machine in .1-.3 ms, because I gave my system a reboot, and sure enough it's consistently between .1-.3ms.

Comment: Re smaller images, I was really hoping you wouldn't say that, because that was the conclusion I came to myself, after thinking about how to optimise etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine once for all which rectangle of the source image will effectively be copied to the destination. Then the most efficient way is to copy row by row, as the rows are contiguous. And `memcpy` is the fastest way.

Comment: Well exactly. I'm using `memcpy` because how fast everyone says it is. That's the basis of my question, is if there's anything else I can do on top of it.

Comment: @J-Cake: "on top of it" is just adding overhead, no ? Your process is data movement only, so use the fastest data movement function. It saturates the bus bandwidth.

Comment: _on top of it_ much less in a literal sense, more sort of what else I can do, generally

Comment: @J-Cake: consider not doing that copy if you can avoid it then. This will be faster.

Comment: Do you think `mmap`ing each line would be sensible? serious question

Comment: @J-Cake: well, data movements involving a disk can be hundred times slower than between RAM locations. My advice to not perform the copy was serious.

Comment: `mmap` operates in memory and would reduce the number of data moves/copies. I'm aware your answer was serious. I'm trying to find more info

Comment: @J-Cake: "would reduce the number of data moves/copies": no.

Comment: My understanding is that `mmap` **can** allow two process's virtual memory to point to the same physical memory?

Comment: @J-Cake: there is no need to resort to shared memory to point to the same physical memory !

Comment: @J-Cake: for the last time, either you copy with `memcpy` or you don't copy.

Comment: AFAIK, mmap can only map pages so your copied lines need to be aligned to a page boundary (both the source and destination). Mapping bytes would be insane for a processor to do. Additionally, mmap is a syscall and so it is pretty expensive (generally >1us and probably much more on Raspberry Pi). So no this is not a good idea.

Comment: @YvesDaoust "*It saturates the bus bandwidth*" I show in my answer why it could not be the case in this example (at least not efficiently) due to the way `memcpy` and processor works ;) . Still `memcpy` should do a pretty good job.